# MySQL : avoid full scan when altering partitioning

Tags: mysql, partition

We dispose of a database  MySQL partitioned over every of our client with a unique ID (it is not a linear partition created with RANGE over a value).

When I create or delete a new partition, with requests :

```
ALTER TABLE "table_name"
    ADD PARTITION (PARTITION "client_id_value" VALUES IN ("client_id_value")); 

ALTER TABLE "table_name" DROP PARTITION "client_id_value";
```

SQL does a table full scan, even if there is no value corresponding to the new partition yet (and I know it). It is problematic as we create and delete a partition in every fitness test we do to ensure the good process of creating specific, separate space in data for the client. One solution would be to keep a partition for testing, but I wonder if we can skip the full scan while altering the table.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You query with something like this? `SELECT FROM table_name WHERE client_id_value = [id] ...` then you can choose to index client_id_value also.

Comment: Hello Raymond, well client_id_value is in fact already indexed, and my SELECT queries are not the problem here. It is when I run the ALTER TABLE commands specified above that I would like to avoid the full scan.

Comment: ALTER TABLE commands always trigger a full table scan you can't avoid it.

Comment: Thanks Raymond, good to know. I guess the answer is to keep a partition for testing then.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- we need to know which type of partitioning is being used.

Comment: Post a bug at bugs.mysql.com .